# How can I hide the scrollbars in TChromium

Tags: delphi, tchromium

Its been a while now and I can't figure out how can I hide the scrollbars in TChromium. Is there a procedure/function or a property for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be done in document, so after it's loaded call e.g.:

```
Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(
  'document.documentElement.style.overflow = ''hidden''',
  '',
  0
);
```